# Why the "--insertion-density" option for randomTrips.py is not valid?

Tags: sumo

I am using Sumo 1.8.0
According to the sumo documentation, "--insertion-density" is an alternative to the "--period" option for the randomTrips.py
https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Trip.html#traffic_volume_arrival_rate
However, when I try to implement it, I get

> randomTrips.py: error: no such option: --insertion-density

Moreover, I checked the py file, and I couldn't find the option in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online documentation always refers to the current development status but you are using an old version. Please update to the most recent version because the option you refer to has been implemented very recently.